# python value error time data %Z

Tags: python, datetime

I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: time data 'Tue, 17 Jul 2018 11:55:34 EDT' does not match format '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z'
```

**Code:**

```
import datetime
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime('Tue, 17 Jul 2018 11:55:34 EDT', '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z')
print(dt.timestamp())
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: The issues lies with the timezone

Comment: Check your locale, maybe you have it set to something else than "en_US"

Comment: Also, this problem is generally a PITA for all but the simplest format strings. Save yourself the headache and let a module like `dateparser` handle the minutia instead.

Comment: According to [this bug report](https://bugs.python.org/issue22377) _the only timezone strings it recognizes are utc, gmt, and whatever is in time.tzname_

Comment: Every post I am finding is saying to use other libraries for dealing with timezone specific strings

Comment: In my case, I have multiple datetimes I need to standardize. This format, with EDT happens to be the least common, but others use +/- xxx and datetime can handle that fine

Answer (score 1):

`EDT` is not identified as a valid timezone string. You may use something other intelligent parser and than automatically return the datetime object without you explicitly specifying the format. My suggestion is to go up with `dateutil`

```
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> parser.parse('Tue, 17 Jul 2018 11:55:34 EDT')
datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 11, 55, 34)
```

Comment: When I run that - - "UnknownTimezoneWarning: tzname EDT identified but not understood.  Pass `tzinfos` argument in order to correctly return a timezone-aware datetime.  In a future version, this will raise an exception.
  category=UnknownTimezoneWarning)"     :')

Comment: Also, if I use: Tue, 17 Jul 2018 11:55:34 -0500 ---- this will yield: 2018-07-17 11:55:34-05:00 which is incorrect of what I'm looking for.